# webpack how turn off transforming imports

Tags: webpack

Webpack requires at least one js entry specified. And it converts imports to one file. Imports now natively supported in browser. How to output the original file without replaced imports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webpack currently doesn't support an ESModule output yet. You can use Rollup, if you are set on wanting to use script `type=module`. This will be a feature added near webpack 5!